# Thunderbird : Compose in HTML temporarily instead of plain text

Tags: thunderbird

Is there a way to allow HTML composition temporarily, while the account settings has been configured as plain text ?

On google, couple of things turned up:

- Holding down the shift key while clicking on reply (disadvantage : no keyboard shortcut)
- Use HTML mode, TB will automatically use plain text when there is no HTML used (disadvantage : sometimes the thread is in HTML, so the HTML will be used when I want to use plain text)

Searched addons, but did not find anything.

Comment: Thanks, this was actually the first google result when searching for almost the same problem - just that I didn't know SHIFT+CLICK did the job.  Personally, I don't care if a have to use a mouse once a month for HTML mail :-P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try using [Keyconfig](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?t=72994) to create a keyboard shortcut equivalent to shift+reply.

Answer (score 5):

check out this article...

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Plain_text_e-mail_%28Thunderbird%29

Answer (score 4):

Further to BenA's answer (sorry, I can't comment yet) about **Keyconfig** a couple of useful links on mozillaZine:

- [Keyconfig manual](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Keyconfig_extension)
- [Thunderbird codes](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Keyconfig_extension:_Thunderbird)

and the actual code relevant to this question is `MsgNewMessage({shiftKey: true})` or replace `MsgNewMessage` part with one of `MsgForwardAsAttachment`, `MsgForwardMessage`, `MsgNewMessage`, `MsgReplyGroup`, `MsgReplySender`, or `MsgReplyToAllMessage`.

Answer (score 2):

That's easy:
Once you click on *Reply*, open the "*Options*" menu, select "*Format*" then click on "*HTML only*" or "*Text & HTML*".

Comment: This is bugged somewhat.  HTML mail is still displayed as HTML when you change to "Plain Text" from this menu.

Comment: Yep - this bug is easily reproducible. Also note that once your email is in "Text" mode, the Options=>Format option disappears. What a user experience nightmare.